# declaring object in variable variable fatal error accessing empty property

Tags: php, object, dynamic

Trying to crate objects dynamically for a plug in system (work in progress)

heres my code using $this->module->load_module('test'); to use the method that creates the dynamic objects. Following code is the function that loads the class's and makes use of an auto loader, i have checked that its getting the correct file etc.

```
<?php 

class BaseModule {

    function __construct() {

    }

    function load_module($module){
        echo 'Module = '.$module.'<br />';
        $object_name = $module . "Controller";
        $this->$$module = new $object_name();
    }
}
```

Here is a test module that it would load when invoking $this->module->load_module('test'); and it creates the object outputting the test strings via echo statements. Heres the code for the test module that was constructed. Which should cause no problems as there is not really a solution but just an output string, but posted any way.

```
<?php

class testController {
        function __construct() {
            echo 'test controller from modules <br />';
        }
}
```

However when running the page i am getting some errors can any one help out?

> Notice: Undefined variable: test in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tealtique/application/modules/BaseModule.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tealtique/application/modules/BaseModule.php on line 11

Comment: Is `$this->$$module` correct? I guess it resolves to `$this->$test`. Maybe you intended `$this->$module`? (one `$`).

Comment: yeah wanted to use a variable variable to dynamically name the objects

Comment: Do you know what line is causing the fatal error?

Comment: according to the error report line 11 sorry missed it off of my quetion i will try and edit

Comment: Are you maybe calling `load_module("")`? That would explain the 'empty property' error.

Comment: i am using $this->module->load_module('test');